# Kafka deleting from only one topic

Tags: apache-kafka, retention, strimzi

I am running Kafka 3.3.1 through Strimzi in my k8s cluster, and have 3 topics currently being read by 1 consumer group. The consumer group is up to date reading the latest offsets (e.g. no lag).

All 3 topics are using the server-default retention time of 7 days (`retention.ms=604800000`), and the cleanup policy is set to the server-default `delete`. However, I can find server log entries from the cleaner process deleting aged-out log entries from only one topic. The two other topics seem to have never been touched by the cleaner process, and running `kafka-console-consumer` against them shows they definitely still have log entries from effectively the beginning of time for those two topics.

Any ideas why the cleaner would only be touching the one topic? All 3 topics I have compared and have the exact same configs, as reported by `kafka-config.sh --describe --all` for each topic.

Answer (score 2):

Takes into account that log segments are deleted only when they are closed.
It means that if you left the default log.segment.bytes at 1 GB and retention time at 7 days, if the log segment is not closed (so 1 GB filled) within 7 days, it will stay longer.
If your producer is slower and doesn't fill a 1 GB segment within 7 days, it won't be never closed, so never deleted.
To better understanding of how segments rolling and deletion works, it's worth reading the following blog post where I explain this in details.

https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/12/17/kafka-segment-retention/